# Return multiple datasets from sql server stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to return through Web Api a Base64 XML output based upon calling a stored procedures which runs 5 different queries.

Stored procedure is not written ( I need to write it )  but there are 5 queries in which the data is completely different tables and columns etc...  so I am wondering if this is even possible?

I know in Oracle you can return multiple cursors, but with SQL Server , can I return into asp.net 4.5  ( mvc  c#  / Ado.net)  multiple datasets or collections?   Any examples of this?

Example of just ONE of the queries

```
   -- Content Tab
SELECT -- vTC.[TemplateId]  
  t.Name as "Client Name and Document"  ,vTC.[SectionName] ,vTC.[ContentId] ,vTC.[ContentName]
  ,vTC.[ContentDescription],vTC.[ContentValue] ,CAL.ContentValue as "Spanish Content" , iif(S.IsClientSection = 1, 'Global Section','Template Section') as "Global or Template Section"
  ,DT.Title as DataType ,iif(vTC.IsRequired = 1, 'Yes', 'No') as "Required" ,vTC.[DisplayType] 
FROM [dbo].[vwTemplateContent] vTC
 left join dbo.Template t on vTC.TemplateId = t.TemplateId
  left join dbo.DataType DT on vTC.DataTypeId = dt.datatypeid
   left join dbo.Section S on S.SectionID = vTC.SectionID
   left join [dbo].[ContentAlternateLanguage] CAL on vTC.ContentId =    CAL.ContentID
  where vTC.templateid in (1) 
  order by DisplayOrder
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are going to get multiple tables then you have to write multiple select statements into your stored procedure like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPName
(
/*Declare your parameters*/
@parm1 dataType
)
AS
BEGIN
/*Write your select statements below*/
-- SELECT * FROM tblName
-- SELECT * FROM tblName2

END
```

You have to fill these records into your DataSet, [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0sdh0b(v=vs.110).aspx) supports multiple table into ADO.net.

Please refer below code to fill your DataSet:

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("YourConnection String");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd = new SqlCommand("SPName", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", id);//if you have parameters.
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
```

After this you can take advantage of different multiple recordsets using

```
ds.Tables[0]
ds.Tables[1]
..
```

Hope it will helps you

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Here's a basic example:

**SQL Proc:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_getStudentsAndClasses
    @ClassName      varchar(50)
,   @IsActive       bit
AS
BEGIN
    --First select is first table
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Students

    --Second select is second table, etc.
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Classes

    --Third table...
    --Can be more complex, as long as there is a result set
    SELECT  s.FirstName
    ,       s.LastName
    FROM    Students            s
    JOIN    StudentSeating      ss
    ON      s.StudentID     =   ss.StudentID
    JOIN    Classes             c
    ON      c.ClassID       =   ss.ClassID
    WHERE   s.IsActive      =   @IsActive
    AND     c.Name          =   @ClassName

END
```

**C# function:**

```
    public DataSet GetDataSet(SqlConnection connection, string storedProcName, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

        var result = new DataSet();
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        dataAdapter.Fill(result);

        return result;
    }
```

**C# usage:**

```
        var connection = new SqlConnection("Your_connection_string");
        var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("ClassName", "Robotics"),       //example of string value
            new SqlParameter("IsActive", true)               //example of numeric value
        };
        var dataSet = GetDataSet(connection, "usp_getStudentsAndClasses", parameters);

        var firstTable = dataSet?.Tables?[0];   //use as any other data table...
```

Notice, it is almost the same code as you would use for a single-table stored procedure, except the data type returned is a `DataSet`, not a `DataTable`. A `DataSet` contains a `DataTableCollection` [More info on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible. You just need to write your select queries and you will get the data in a `DataSet`. If you have a single select query, you will get `DataTable` and if you have number of select queries (Say 5), then you will get a `DataSet` that has 5 `DataTable`s. It is so simple. Just write your procedure and have fun.

**Edit:**
Example of Stored Procedure (pseudo code) is given below:

```
create Proc Name_Of_Proc
(
   @FirstParam DataType,
   @SecondParam DataType
)
AS
Begin
   Select statement 1
   Select statement 2 
   Select statement 3 --and so on upto n.
end
```

You need to do this in your database. After doing this, you need to execute this procedure from c# by using ADO.NET. You need to use `SqlConnection` `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` object to do this. You can search on google or SO itself for more examples. One such link on SO is [How to execute Stored procedure in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942171/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp-with-different-parameters)

Comment: How do i write sproc and c# ado.net  ? 

create sproc  SprocName ....

select a,b,c,d,e from table a
select z,h,m,i  from table b
select y,u,a,bb from table c