# get all combo value from sql server in one hit

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

On my page i have multiple combos/dropdown in one screen and all the combos/dropdown are loading data from SQL. for example if there is 20 combo then 20 time database would be called to fetch data in one request. Is there any way to get all combos data in one SQL hit?

Comment: In my opinion you should get only selected values and texts for each combo and it is easy in one query. This is enough to fill the form but if you will try to edit the form so you can get values for each combo on request (like clicking, focus on combo etc.) and fill it in this moment.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: I think it would be pretty challenging to have the data for 20 comboboxes in a single query. The query itself wouldn't be a big deal but then what? You will have to split all the data to each combobox. It sounds like not a good plan at all to me. If you are concerned about performance you can always cache the data for your comboboxes to avoid being forced to repeatedly pull the same data. But at the same time a query to populate a combobox should be pretty simple and fast anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return multiple datasets from sql server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013747/return-multiple-datasets-from-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

Atually it is possible to return two (or more) datatables from stored procedure (I'm talking about MS SQL)

Something like

```
create procedure SampleDataSetResult
as
begin
 select * from table1
 select * from table2
end
```

Then this can be consumed like

```
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "SampleDataSetResult";
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(dataset);

    // here you can use dataset tables
}
```

However this approach works with raw data from database. Also it contains datatables that do not have names to be analyzed. The only one is to synchronize datatable index between SP and source code and process this datatable data according to its index. Like `dataset.Tables[0]` - is treated like combo data 1 etc. This can be tricky and all SP modifications have to be synchronized with source code.
Also having 20 combos on one page sounds a little bit strange. I suppose that there will be combos data to be shown that depends from data selected in the previous combo.

I do not see any reason to save SQL queries count right now for you. If you have web page then you can try to use MVC approach and wrap database calls with view model method calls.